# Command not found in elif comparison > bash

Tags: bash, unix

For some reason commands are not running after the first if statement.
"/usr/local//backup.sh: sleep: not found" for example..

The first if statement goes like:

```
if [ "$command" == "start -c" ]; then
echo -e "${ORANGE}Starting website backup...${E}"
sleep 1
DT=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo -e "${ORANGE}Started backup at $DT ${E}"
sleep 1
tar -zcvf web-$DT.tar.gz /usr/local/www/nginx
echo -e "${ORANGE}Compatced files, moving to backup directory${E}"
sleep 1
mv web-$DT.tar.gz $PATH/web-$DT.tar.gz
echo -e "${CYAN}Moved to backups ($PATH/web-$DT.tar.gz)\nDo you want to upload to ftp?${E}\n${CYAN} 'y' or 'n'?${E}"
read answer
if [ "$answer" == "y" ]; then
    echo -e "${ORANGE}Uploading to ftp server...${E}"
    sleep 1
    if ftp -in -u ftp://$USER:$PASS@$HOST/Backups/f $PATH/web-$DT.tar.gz; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}Uploaded! Bye!${E}"
    else
        echo -e "${ORANGE}Couldn't upload with ftp command, trying with curl...${E}"
        sleep 1
        curl -T "$PATH/web-$DT.tar.gz" -u $USER:$PASS ftp://$HOST/Backups/f/
        echo -e "${GREEN}Uploaded! Bye!${E}"
    fi
else
    echo -e "${GREEN}Bye!${E}"
fi
```

Everything works fine inside this statement, however, after the elif compassion it just doesn't.

Here's the problematic code:

```
elif [ "$command" == "start -d" ]; then
echo -e "${ORANGE}Starting database backup...${E}"
sleep 1
DT=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo -e "${ORANGE}Started backup at $DT ${E}"
sleep 1
umask 177
echo -e "${ORANGE}Dumping database 'account'\n${E}"
mysqldump --user=$DBUSER --password=$DBPASS --host=$HOST account > $PATH/account-$DT.sql
sleep 1
echo -e "${ORANGE}Dumping database 'game'\n${E}"
mysqldump --user=$DBUSER --password=$DBPASS --host=$HOST game > $PATH/game-$DT.sql
sleep 1
echo -e "${ORANGE}Dumping database 'forum'\n${E}"
mysqldump --user=$DBUSER --password=$DBPASS --host=$HOST forum > $PATH/forum-$DT.sql
sleep 1
echo -e "${CYAN}Moved to backups ($PATH/<database-date>.sql)\nDo you want to upload to ftp?${E}\n${CYAN} 'y' or 'n'?${E}"
read answer
if [ "$answer" == "y" ]; then
    echo -e "${ORANGE}Uploading to ftp server...${E}"
    sleep 1
    curl -T "$PATH/account-$DT.sql" -u $USER:$PASS ftp://$HOST/Backups/f/Databases/
    curl -T "$PATH/game-$DT.sql" -u $USER:$PASS ftp://$HOST/Backups/f/Databases/
    curl -T "$PATH/forum-$DT.sql" -u $USER:$PASS ftp://$HOST/Backups/f/Databases/
    sleep 1
    echo -e "${GREEN}Uploaded! Bye!${E}"
else
    echo -e "${GREEN}Bye!${E}"
fi
```

and then I just ended it..

```
else
    echo -e "${RED}Sorry! Not found${E}"
fi
```

As you can see there's spaces in the if statements and all of that, so what's wrong with this??

I've the #!/bin/bash up top as well, all the variables exist too.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Got the same output with set -x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have overwritten the value of the `PATH` variable at some point in your code.  The shell needs that variable in order to know where to find programs like `sleep` (Hence the "not found" error).  Name your path variable something else.

Comment: "PATH" is the backup directory, not the bin dir

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: No, the shell always treats `PATH` as the command search path.  If you set `PATH` to the backup directory, then Bash will look for commands in the backup directory, which probably won't work out too well.

Comment: This is why you should always use lowercase variable names.

Comment: Interesting, didn't thought about that. thanks for the info!